# Get value from array in mongodb collection

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aws-documentdb

```
collection:
{    
    "username" : "gorim99949@x1post.com",
    "channels" : [ 
        {
            "channelName" : "yyyyy",
            "id" : 383,
            "url" : "https://xxxxxxxxx",
        }
    ],
}

@Document(collection = "user_masters")
public class UserMasters {
  @Field("username")
  private String userName;

  @DBRef
  private List<UserChannels> UserChannels userChannels;
   ******getter and setter*********

@Document(collection="channels")
public class UserChannels {
  private String url;
 ************getter/setter****************


Repository class
public UserMasters  findByUserName(String username);

@Test method
Query: userRepository.findByUserName(userName).getUserChannels().getUrl();
```

how can i get value of url from array in the collection in mongodb. I am unable to read values in the array in the collection. thanks in advance for your help

Comment: userChannels is a `List` why don't you try (for example) `...getUserChannels().get(0).getUrl()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need a custom query to do that.
Run this query:
db.collection.aggregate({$match: {username: "gorim99949@x1post.com"}}, {$project: {"userChannels": "$channels.url"}});
It will return:
[{"_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),"userChannels": ["https://xxxxxxxxx"]}].
You can remove _id from returning document by setting it to 0 in projection.